# Wt WText Scrollbar

Tags: c++, wt

I have a little question about Wt. When I create WText (child of a WContainerWidget and having a long long text), Scrollbars are not created for this WText. I have tried many things like setting overflow (with setOverflow function of WContainerWidget), putting this text class into  WScrollArea and etc..

If you have some kind of opinions about that problem, I would be glad.

Thanks everyone by now.
Mustafa

Edit: Code example

```
MyApplication::MyApplication(Wt::WEnvironment const &env)
  : Wt::WApplication(env)
{
  std::string str = "..." // a very long html string
  auto text = new Wt::WText(str, Wt::XHTMLUnsafeText);

  root()->setOverflow(OverflowAuto);
  root()->addWidget(text);
}
```

Comment: Showing your code would be helpful

Comment: I have added some code. I could not add all my code. I think this example gives the point.

Comment: You should set some fixed height to your widget. If the text size exceeds that height, you'll get a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Wt::WTextArea` instead of `WText`, if its a large file. Its scrollable.